# Multiple Spring Cloud Functions in one project for deployment on AWS Lambda

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am currently using Spring Cloud Function, and I want to deploy my functions on AWS Lambda, using the adapter for AWS.

Till now all the Spring Cloud Function implemented was a single function with the following structure.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.demo")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Handler for lamda:

import org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.SpringBootRequestHandler;

public class DemoHandler extends SpringBootRequestHandler<DemoRequest, DemoResponse> {
}

I understand that this part of the code is Depricated.

Interface to define the Endpoint:

```
@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Demoapi<DemoRequest, DemoResponse>{
    @PostMapping(value = "/v1/demo")
    public ResponseEntity<DemoResponse> demo(@RequestBody DemoRequest demoInfo);

}
```

Followed by the controller where the @RestController was defined

Part of the controller:

```
@RestController
public class Democontroller implements Demoapi<DemoRequest, DemoResponse>{
        static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Democontroller.class);
        
@Autowired
private DemoService demoService;

@Override
public ResponseEntity<DemoResponse> demo(@RequestBody DemoRequest demoInfo) {
    DemoResponse demoResponse=new DemoResponse();
    try {
        demoResponse = demoService.demofun(demoInfo);
  ........
.........
.........
```

This setup works perfectly. When deploying to Lambda, I provide Handler as com.demo.DemoHandler in the AWS console, and in the Environment Variable under FUNCTION_NAME I give the DemoController class with the Starting letter in small caps i.e demoController and the lamda works fine when tested in the console as well as directed from an API Gateway.

Currently I am working on a project where it is required to perform all the CRUD operations within one Spring Boot Application and deploy it as a single lambda.

I want to know how this can be achieved using similar structure within the application.

All help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a similar result using an approach with this library:
https://github.com/MelonProjectCom/lambda-http-router

```
 @PathPostMapping("/example/test")
 public String example(@Body String body) {
    return "Hello World! - body: " + body;
 }
```